# django filtering querysets causes 'AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.' with forms within models.py

Tags: django, filtering, python-3.4, django-queryset

During the development of our current django-project (django 1.7.1) we reach the task to mark some database-entries as deleted and remove them from user's sight but not completely from db.

A fast straightforward solution I found [django-logicaldelete](https://github.com/paltman/django-logicaldelete) (exactly what we want to do!)

Following the instruction from django-logicaldelete I installed logicaldelete with pip and added it as INSTALLED_APP to settings.py

Only thing left was to add logicaldelete in models.py and admin.py an inherit from it

```
...
import logicaldelete

class MyModel(logicaldelete.models.Model){...}
...
```

---

```
...
import logicaldelete
    
class MyModelAdmin(logicaldelete.admin.ModelAdmin){...}
...
```

So far so good :)
Trying to run the project now causes an 'AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.' - Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 414, in get_field_by_name
        return self._name_map[name]
    AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute '_name_map'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 561, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
    cache = self._related_many_to_many_cache
AttributeError: 'Options' object has no attribute '_related_many_to_many_cache'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\eclipse\workspacePraxis\promotionsdatenbank\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 354, in execute
        django.setup()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 21, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
        app_config.import_models(all_models)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "C:\eclipse\workspacePraxis\promotionsdatenbank\personen\models.py", line 144, in <module>
        class PromovendChoice(forms.Form):
      File "C:\eclipse\workspacePraxis\promotionsdatenbank\personen\models.py", line 149, in PromovendChoice
        promovend_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Promovend.objects.all(), to_field_name='nachname', empty_label="Promovend")
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 191, in all
        return self.get_queryset()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\logicaldelete\managers.py", line 15, in get_queryset
        return LogicalDeleteQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).filter(date_removed__isnull=True)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 691, in filter
        return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 709, in _filter_or_exclude
        clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1287, in add_q
        clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1314, in _add_q
        current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1138, in build_filter
        lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1076, in solve_lookup_type
        _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py", line 1339, in names_to_path
        field, model, direct, m2m = opts.get_field_by_name(name)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 416, in get_field_by_name
        cache = self.init_name_map()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 445, in init_name_map
        for f, model in self.get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model():
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 563, in get_all_related_m2m_objects_with_model
        cache = self._fill_related_many_to_many_cache()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 577, in _fill_related_many_to_many_cache
        for klass in self.apps.get_models():
      File "C:\Python34\lib\functools.py", line 428, in wrapper
        result = user_function(*args, **kwds)
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 168, in get_models
        self.check_models_ready()
      File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
        raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
    django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

I read about that problem since django 1.7 and as solution

```
import django
django.setup()
```

is given. Here I doesn't work to add those lines.
Tried to add it in logicaldelete.managers.py and logicaldelete.query.py

Seems I've got the wrong Idea what causes the problem.

The only part of my own code shown in the errors' traceback ist this call within a form:

```
promovend_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Promovend.objects.all(), to_field_name='nachname', empty_label="Promovend")
```

Hope you know a way to solve this...

If not I'll just override the delete-method and add a manager on my own.

## **Update no. 3**

I've implemented a BaseModel and a suitable Manager on my own (it hardly differs from logicaldelete)

```
class SoftDeleteBaseModel(models.Model):

    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    objects = SoftDeleteManager(False)
    objects_deleted = SoftDeleteManager(True)
    all_objects = models.Manager()
    
    def delete(self):
        related_models = [relation.get_accessor_name() for relation in self._meta.get_all_related_objects()]
        
        for model_objects in rleated_models:
            related_objects = getattr(self, model_objects).all()

            for related_object in related_objects:
                if not issubclass(related_object.__class__, SoftDeleteBaseModel):  
                    break
                related_object.delete()
        
        self.deleted= True
        self.save()
        
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

---

```
class SoftDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    
    def __init__(self, show_deleted=False):
        super(SoftDeleteManager, self).__init__()
        self.show_deleted = show_deleted
         
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(SoftDeleteManager, self).get_queryset()
        return qs.filter(deleted=self.show_deleted)
```

Unfortunately the same error occurs. Importing *django* an calling *django.setup()* in my managers.py file doesn't work either.

There is some problem calling the (self-made) manager with

```
objects = SoftDeleteManager(False)
objects_deleted = SoftDeleteManager(True)
all_objects = models.Manager()
```

Seems the SoftDeleteManger isn't ready (loaded) while my Model wants to refer to it..

## Update no. 4

New findings:

Suggesting the error lies within my form wasn't that bad! I wondered using `queryset = model.objects.all()` with standard-manager works fine, replacing it with my **SoftDeleteManager** causes an error...

The idea came up: Why not adding a filter to that codeline using standard-manager?
`queryset = models.objects.all().filter(deleted=False)`
That code causes the AppRegistryNotReady-error as well - so the root cause seems to be filtering the querysets within my self-made Manager...

#### Edit

I found a similiar problem with filtering querysets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353959/django-filter-query-doesnt-work).
But as mentioned at the top I tried using `import django` and `django.setup()` without success...

## Update no. 5

After reading a hundred times calling `django.setup()` would solve the problem I called it within my *models.py*, expecting the an error or a successful run... but nothing happens at all. Running the project creates a python-process but there is no output neither the development server starts...

Greetings,
Tobi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a "hidden" solution in a previous post somewhere (I unfortunately lost the source):

There is *django.form* used to be in my *models.py*. Supposing that forms' command causes the error I ***re-structured*** my app and created a seperate *forms.py* file for that form. Finally it works perfeclty!

Comment: you don't need to call django.setup() in that file, I think

Comment: The problem was using code that depends on models in the models.py file. django loads all these files on bootstrap and they weren't ready when requested

Comment: Your right! `django.setup()` isn't required...
The django-world becomes more clear. Thx again.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a problem with that library. I suggest implementing you own logical delete (which is rather easy with a LogicalDeleteManager and a LogicalDeleteModel) or using a lower version of django

As a simplistic example:

```
class MyLogicalDeleteManager(models.Manager):
    def __init__(self, show_deleted_objects=False)
        super(MyLogicalDeleteManager, self).__init__()
        self.show_deleted_objects = show_deleted_objects

    def get_queryset(self):
         qs = super(MyLogicalDeleteManager, self).get_queryset()
         return qs.filter(deleted=self.show_deleted_objects)

class MyLogicalDeleteModel(models.Model):
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = MyLogicalDeleteManager(False)
    deleted_objects = MyLogicalDeleteManager(True)
    all_objects = models.Manager()

    def delete(self):
        # Maybe check FK constraints with self._meta.get_all_related_objects()
        self.deleted = True
        self.save()
```

Comment: Hoped to pass that step... 
it has been roughly planned similiar to your solution - thx for the code-example :)

Comment: It will take some time, but I've found it to be easier in the long run to make these things work exactly like you want to :)

Comment: Unfortunately writing my own BaseModel and Manager doesn't work either :/ The same error occurs...
Come to think my own form calling "objects.all()" crashes - but I don't know why

Comment: That's strange... did you upgrade django recently? does the error occur on every model or just the new one?

Comment: The error occurs while using a form of a model only - or more precisely calling the models' (overridden) manager within that form.

Comment: New findings:

Suggesting the error lies within my form wasn't that bad! I wondered using `queryset = model.objects.all()` with standard-manager works fine, replacing it with my **SoftDeleteManager** causes an error... the idea came up: Why not adding a filter to that codeline using standard-manager?: `queryset = models.objects.all().filter(deleted=False)`
That code causes the AppRegistryNotReady-Error as well - so the root cause semms to be filtering the querysets within my self-made Manager...

Comment: Finally found the solution - thx for your time and help. I think I hadn't found out without your "motivation" to play with some code-lines.